# Javascript object that inherits QWidget

Tags: javascript, qt, inheritance, qtscript

I am doing something in Javascript and Qt, and for my purpose, I need a **javascript object that inherits QWidget**. So far, I have tried the following:

```
function Test()
{
    QWidget.call(this);
    this.button = new QPushButton("test");
    this.layout().insertWidget(1,this.button);
    this.button.clicked.connect(this.slot);
}

Test.prototype.slot = function()
{
    print("Test button clicked");
}

Test.prototype = new QWidget();
```

I instantiate object from the class "Test" and with the call of the `show()` method, I get the widget:

```
var testVariable = new Test();
testVariable.show();
```

However, I get the following interpreter error:

> Error: In run/evaluate: TypeError:
>   Function.prototype.connect: target is
>   not a function

If I change the line `this.button.clicked.connect(this.slot);` to call a static method defined like this:

```
    this.button.clicked.connect(Test.slot);
...
...
    Test.slot = function () { /* code */ }
```

the program runs fine, but static method is a no-no. I don't want anyone to call `slot()` except the instantiated object.

What is wrong with this picture? Has anyone had experience with Javascript objects inheriting Qt objects?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I might figured this out. So the magic here is:

```
Test.prototype = new QWidget();
```

needs to be **before** the constructor, also the constructor has to take ["parent" argument](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#QWidget) too. And last but not least, in `connect()` there are two arguments: first is which class contains the slot (in my case it is `this`) and the name of the slot with `this` pointer.

So, having this in mind, the above code will look like this:

```
Test.prototype = new QWidget();
function Test(parent)
{
    QWidget.call(this, parent);
    this.button = new QPushButton("test");
    this.layout().insertWidget(1, this.button);
    this.button.clicked.connect(this, this.slot);
}

Test.prototype.slot = function()
{
    print("Test button clicked");
}
```

This is to whom it may concern.